# Rounded corners from gtk theme have black background

Tags: gtk, picom

[image]

I am using i3wm on Manjaro Linux. My gtk theme has rounded corners for menus, but they still have a sharp black background. I am using picom compositor, and I think the issue is something related to that. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not succeed with the solution from mattia.b89, here is a workaround. I simply chose not to have rounded corners for those kind of menus. I added this to my gtk.css in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/

```css
menu,
.csd .menu,
.csd .dropdown,
.csd .context-menu {
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

(I found this suggestion somewhere on a GitLab repo, I can't remember which)

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the source code directly and recompile `picom`. Fortunately for you (us) the work has already been done, so there is (at least one) patch to overcome this issue *(i.e. [https://github.com/sdhand/picom])*.

One more time, fortunately, you can just use any AUR package which provide it *(i.e. [https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/picom-rounded-corners])*.

Comment: I installed the AUR package but it made no difference, are there any config changes I need to make?

Comment: Probably you need; I don't have that system in my hands; to play it safe, delete your old configuration and start from a new one...